# how to call controller action method from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following _PartilView.cshtml

```
 @model= Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

 @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
 {
   <li data-thumb="@Url.Action("Sample", "Image", new { imageid = item.ImageValue})"></li>
 }
```

but this is not call to the `Sample` method in `Image` controller, since I cant use JavaScript in PartialView, what the approach would be better to solve this ?

Comment: Having a call to a method as a html attribute makes no sense. What are you wanting to do?

Comment: I want to get image source to `<li  data-thumb="Image_Source"></li>`

Comment: What is `"Image_Source"`? Is that the value returned by property `ImageValue`? If so, then just `<li data-thumb="@item.ImageValue"></li>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke it returns a image URL , seems i need to do when I seed data to Partial View

Comment: When u get the Image id i.e Model.Users[n].ImageValue , you can fetch the image url also in the model right ? that way you can Model.User[n].ImageURL in data-thumb attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use @Html.Action not @Url.Action

```
@model= Project.ViewModels.UserViewModel

     @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
     {
       <li data-thumb="@Html.Action("Sample", "Image", new { imageid = item.ImageValue})"></li>
     }
```

@Url.Action()

It generates a URL as per provided action name, controllername, route object.
It contains 8 overload methods.

@Html.Action()

It calls child action in a controller and return Html string as result.
It contains 6 overload methods.