# Image path return getting as string value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have following method to get an Image path in a Project

```
    public ActionResult RenderImage(string imageid, string pathvalue)
    {
        try
        {
            var URL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[pathvalue].ToString();
            var path = Path.Combine(URL, imageid + ".jpg");
            return base.File(path, "image/jpeg");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I want to take this returning Image path as string ,  for that I tried something like this

```
ControllerName ns = new ControllerName ();

var path = ns .RenderImage("id", "path");   
string imageurl = path.ToString();
```

but this is not getting image path as "C:/User/Data/Image.jpg" its getting value as  "System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult"

How to solve this

Comment: Did you take a look at what methods are available to `System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult` namely the [`Filename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult.filename(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult.FileName)  method.

Comment: Why are you calling a controller method that returns a `FileResult` if you just want a string? What is it that your really trying to do here? And if its related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646958/how-to-call-controller-action-method-from-partial-view), then why are you not setting the corret path in the first place using `Url.Content()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm try to get exact image url as model property object

Comment: So just format the property in the first place using `Path.Combine(path, imageid + ".jpg");` when you pass the model to the view. The answer you have accepted is nonsense. And if you do want to seriously degrade performance by calling a server method each time `User` in your collection, then all you need to `return Content(Path.Combine(path, imageid + ".jpg"));` - creating a path to read and return a file and then just get the its filename and throw away the file makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var ns = new ControllerName ();

var path = ns.RenderImage("id", "path");  

 var fileResult = path  as FilePathResult;

    if (fileResult != null)
    {

        string imageurl = fileResult.FileName;
        imageurl = imageurl.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
    }
```

Comment: your answer is seems correct , but as imageurl I'm getting something like this `"D:\\Folder\\Location\\A.jpg"` how to remove "\\" form above and get url like this `"D:\Folder\Location\A.jpg"`

Comment: @kez updated . Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp for more details

Comment: Great. I'm glad it helps